# If the Time stops

Tags: time

What will happen if the time stops? If everything freezes (by saying 'everything' I mean 'everything'), we will not be able to see anything (and our body also freezes). Then what is the use of time-stopping?

Comment: What is the use of time-stopping? How can there be a use for something that cannot happen? That's like asking "What is the use for unicorns?" This is not a physics question.

Comment: Neither is the question what is the use for popcorn.

Answer (score 4):

Since physics is about what is observable and since you need time to observe any phenomenon, if time stops, nothing happens from a physics perspective. You can pause time as much as you want, no consequence.

Comment: What if photons also freeze?

Comment: Read my answer one more time.

Comment: OP's question is actually not that trivial. Photons in fact do not experience time and they are so important to physics. Also, in GR time is just a coordinate, so coordinate time stopping may not mean nothing happening.